# Set ViewPager's adapter via Data Binding

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Trying to use Android's [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) to adapter for a `ViewPager` (controls slidable `Fragments`).

**FooPagerAdapter.kt**:

```
class FooPagerAdapter(fm: Fragmentmanager, private val mFragments: List<BarFragment>) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
  override fun getItem(position: int): Fragment {
    return mFragments(position)
  }

  override fun getCount(): Int {
    return mFragments.size
  }
}
```

If done from the **Activity, it would look like**:

```
  ..
  mFooViewPager.adapter = FooPagerAdapter(fragmentFamanager, fragmentsList)
  ..
```

---

**Question:**

Now how does one transfer adapter functionality to the binding file to update fragments ViewPager using Data Binding?

---

**Edit:**

As I understand it has to be something like this.

**activity_foo.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  ..
  app:fragments"${viewModel.fragments}"/>
```

And then in a **FooViewModel.kt:**

```
fun getFragments(): LiveData<List<BarFragment>>? = mFragments

companion object {
  @BindingAdapter("bind:fragments")
  fun setAdapter(pager: ViewPager, adapter: BarPagerAdapter) {
    pager.adapter = adapter
  }
}
```

---

**Edit2:**

Decided to use a `ViewModel` directly (without binding) to set `ViewPager`'s adapter.

**activity_foo.xml:**

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.foo.bar.viewmodels.FooViewModel"/>
    </data>
    ..
      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          ..
          app:adapter="%{viewModel.adapter}"/>
```

**FooViewModel.kt:**

```
class FooViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
  ..
  fun setAdapter(pager: ViewPager, fragments:List<PeriodFragment>) {
    pager.adapter = PeriodsPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager!!, periods)
  }
```

Getting:

> Error:...layout\activity_foo.xml:39 attribute 'com.foo.bar:adapter' not found

Comment: @tynn Well, I (myself) would like to see a simplest example how to do it :-)

Comment: Then the question is too broad. There're different possible ways to do so. You should give it a try and when you have issues with it come back here for some solutions.

Comment: @tynn I have updated the question, see **Edit**.

Comment: It should be `app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}"`. You need to use `@` instead of `%` or `$` so that the binding is being identified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `@BindingAdapter` should be static in Java, thus be annotated with `@JvmStatic`. Additionally you're supposed to skip all namespaces with the binding attributes in the adapter definition. Also the second parameter needs to reference a type you want to set. In your case this is `LiveData<List<BarFragment>>`. Then you can create the adapter statically.

```
companion object {
  @JvmStatic
  @BindingAdapter("fragments")
  fun setAdapter(pager: ViewPager, fragments: LiveData<List<BarFragment>>) {
    pager.adapter = createAdapterForFragments(fragments)
  }
}
```

But if `fragments` would be a `PagerAdapter`, a binding adapter is not necessary at all. As a default implementation the compiler looks for a given setter method for the attribute. So if you use `app:adapter`, the `setAdapter()` method will be used automatically. Therefore it should be sufficient to just put this adapter definition in the layout.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  ...
  app:adapter"@{viewModel.fragments}"/>
```

I'd suggest to use the latter and setup the adapter with the `viewModel` not with the data binding.

A little data binding convenience for `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` you'll find with [`ViewPagerDataBinding`](https://github.com/v2rc/Supplies/blob/master/binding/src/main/java/berlin/volders/supplies/binding/adapter/ViewPagerDataBinding.java).

Comment: Good answer. But don't you think `viewModel.fragments` is a bit weird? Shouldn't it be replaced with adapter reference?

Comment: @Rehan I was expecting `fragments` to be an instance of `PagerAdapter`. Just saw it might actually be an instance of `LiveData`.

Comment: @tynn thank you for clarification. Decided to drop binding, getting error (see **Edit2**). Any clues?

Comment: @tynn One, thing after fixing all covered issues, getting _com.foo.bar.databinding does not exist_ on the `ViewPager Fragment`. Works fine back again, once the binding is removed from the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Even if these errors are cryptic, these have information about possible solutions. But these are to extensive for comments for sure. Try to find any massage standing out.

Comment: Ok, used Gradle option to get full error description. It turned out I had to define public variable `adapter` as well, along with `setAdapter` - to work properly. Resolved.

Comment: Where are you getting instance of  `FragmentManager`? I can' see any.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt thanks a lot. The repo was removed. You'll now find a link to a fork.

Comment: How do you implement createAdapterForFragments?